# Running logrotate for apache2 hourly not working

Tags: cron, debian, apache2, logrotate

I'm trying to get logrotate to rotate my apache2 logs every hour (on the hour - at XX:xx:00), I know there are a few posts about this already, but it is just not working for me regardless of what I try, it continues to rotate daily. I'm running apache2 on Debian 11.

Here are the things I have already tried:

- I have moved logtorate from cron.daily to cron.hourly
- logtotate seems to point to /etc/logrotate.conf which contains the code below
- I have changed the /etc/crontab to have the hourly cron run at 0 minutes (code below)
- I have restarted apache2, logrotate and cron services.

Content of the logrotate file in cron.daily:

```
#!/bin/sh

# skip in favour of systemd timer
if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
    exit 0
fi

# this cronjob persists removals (but not purges)
if [ ! -x /usr/sbin/logrotate ]; then
    exit 0
fi

/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
EXITVALUE=$?
if [ $EXITVALUE != 0 ]; then
    /usr/bin/logger -t logrotate "ALERT exited abnormally with [$EXITVALUE]"
fi
exit $EXITVALUE
```

Content of /etc/logrotate.conf

```
hourly
rotate 24
create
include /etc/logrotate.d
```

Inside /etc/logrotate there is an apache2 file which contains this:

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
    hourly
    missingok
    rotate 48
    notifempty
    create 640 root adm
    sharedscripts
    prerotate
    if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then
        run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate
    fi
    endscript
    postrotate
    if pgrep -f ^/usr/sbin/apache2 > /dev/null; then
        invoke-rc.d apache2 reload 2>&1 | logger -t apache2.logrotate
    fi
    endscript
}
```

Content of /etc/crontab:
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

```
0 * * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
0 0 * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
0 0 * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
0 0 1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

Any ideas on what other things I can try? I've run out of ideas!

UPDATE : Using John Hanleys suggestions I have been able to get close to what I'm hoping to ahcieve, but its not rotating at an exact time, despite indicating the following in the logrotate.timer the following:

```
hourly[Unit]
Description=Daily rotation of log files
Documentation=man:logrotate(8) man:logrotate.conf(5)

[Timer]
OnCalendar=hourly
AccuracySec=1m
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

The result is that the logs are getting rotated every hour, but I need them rotating at a (more) exact time), this is what I currently have since making the changes yesterday:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  18K May 23 18:54 access.log.14
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  11K May 23 19:59 access.log.13
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 1.3K May 23 20:54 access.log.12
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  927 May 23 21:25 access.log.11
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 3.5K May 23 22:52 access.log.10
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  534 May 23 23:46 access.log.9
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 1005 May 24 00:58 access.log.8
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  982 May 24 02:00 access.log.7
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 1.1K May 24 02:52 access.log.6
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 1.8K May 24 03:56 access.log.5
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 1.1K May 24 04:52 access.log.4
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  514 May 24 05:54 access.log.3
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 2.1K May 24 06:58 access.log.2
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 1.7K May 24 07:41 access.log.1
```

UPDATE:
Well now I'm stumped! The error.log are rotating correctly, but the access.log are not:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  1.6K May 24 08:59 access.log.10
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   740 May 24 09:00 error.log.10
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   549 May 24 09:25 access.log.9
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   740 May 24 10:00 error.log.9
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   464 May 24 10:38 access.log.8
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   370 May 24 11:00 error.log.8
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  3.9K May 24 11:51 access.log.7
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   658 May 24 12:00 error.log.7
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  5.0K May 24 12:03 access.log.6
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   370 May 24 13:00 error.log.6
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   589 May 24 13:57 access.log.5
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   370 May 24 14:00 error.log.5
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  1.3K May 24 14:54 access.log.4
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   370 May 24 15:00 error.log.4
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   452 May 24 15:58 access.log.3
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   370 May 24 16:00 error.log.3
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  6.4K May 24 16:56 access.log.2
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   370 May 24 17:00 error.log.2
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   889 May 24 17:54 access.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   691 May 24 18:00 error.log.1
```

Comment: Logrotate runs via a timer. Review `/etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/logrotate.timer`. If the timer runs daily your logs will rotate no sooner than daily. Note: you are using anacron, which I do not use. That might affect what must be configured.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know what! You are right, it does state daily there and also has an interesting accuracy setting that I was also unaware of. I've changed the `OnCalendar=daily` to `OnCalendar=hourly` and will see if that sorts it. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Post an answer once you test and verify the solution.

Comment: Will do. Do you know if any service needs restarting after making the change?

Comment: I don't think so. Use the command `systemctl list-timers` to list all the timers to verify. However, when I make major changes like this, I schedule downtime which includes rebooting the system so I might be missing a required service restart.

Comment: John, thanks to your help I have been able to get close to what I'm looking for, I have updated the question above, do you know if there is a way to get them to rotate at an exact time? I would have thought the "accuracy" field set to 1m would have been what I needed, but as you can see, they're a bit all over the place. Any further ideas? Thanks. (I rebooted the server as it's not yet live).

Comment: To add to this, the `systemctl list-timers` shows that it should run at exactly the top of the hour (at xx:xx:00).

Comment: This [article](https://opensource.com/article/20/7/systemd-timers) talks about controlling accuracy. Make sure your system/VM is not sleeping or similar. I am not sure how the wakeup process works in that case.

Comment: I've further updated above, I had landed on the same page you've referenced and changed `logrotate.timer` to `OnCalendar=*-*-* *:00:00` which is half working (it only works for error.log. I'm lost as to why the `error.log` is rotating correctly and `access.log` is not.